# How to access Configuration within an IHostingStartup implementation?

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

Trying to get access to `IConfiguration` from within an `IHostingStartup` implementation and constructor injection is not supported.

The normal `Startup.cs` implementation allows for `IConfiguration` to be injected making it easy to access from within `ConfigureService()` and `Configure()` methods.

What is the best practice way for gaining access to configuration?

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload on some builder methods (i.e. `ConfigureLogging()` `ConfigureAppConfiguration()` `ConfigureServices()` that allows for a WebHostBuilderContext to be passed into the Action.

The [WebHostBuilderContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuildercontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1) provides access to the HostingEnvironment and Configuration

```cs
    public class HostingStartupConfiguration : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
                {
                    // clear providers set from host application
                    if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                {
                    if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                        Console.WriteLine("we are in dev mode");

                    ...
                })
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    ...

                    // get assemblies based on configuration to load as Application Parts
                    var assemblies = GetControllerAssemblies(context.Configuration);

                    // register controllers application parts from external assemblies
                    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
                    {
                        builder.AddApplicationPart(assembly);
                    }

                    ...
                });
        }
```

Comment: `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;` is required.